# In python, how to find out how many sets of numbers in the sentences

Tags: python

For example, if there is a sentence "I have 8 pens and my friend have 7 pens"
I know how to use  re.findall to extract the number and the outcome will be ['8', '7']. However, i want to figure out how many sets of numbers in the sentence, which the answer suppose to be 2. Can someone help me to do it? thank you

Comment: If you mean to say number of numbers, then you can do like this to get it- `len(re.findall(r'\d+', 'I have 8 pens and my friend have 7 pens'))`

Comment: It's unclear if you mean proper a python `set` of numbers (no duplicates in output), or are using it in a generic "group of numbers" context (duplicates allowed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use the length of the `findall()` output?

```
>>> sent =  "I have 8 pens and my friend have 7 pens"
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\d+', sent)
['8', '7']
>>> len(re.findall(r'\d+', sent))
2
```

Or since you asked for the set of numbers, convert the list to a set too (excluding any doubles).

```
>>> sent =  "I have 8 pens and my 8 friend have 7 pens"
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\d+', sent)
['8', '8', '7']
>>> len(re.findall(r'\d+', sent))
3
>>> len(set(re.findall(r'\d+', sent)))
2
```

Answer (score 1):

To find how many numbers are in a string, you can find the length of the list you created with your `re.findall` call.

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: sentence = "I have 3 tacos, 2 burritos, and 3 tortas"

In [3]: re.findall(r'\d+', sentence)
Out[3]: ['3', '2', '3']

In [4]: len(re.findall(r'\d+', sentence))
Out[4]: 3
```

To find how many unique numbers are present in the string, convert the list into a set and find the length of that.

```
In [5]: len(set(re.findall(r'\d+', sentence)))
Out[5]: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Cant you use `len(re.findall())` find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
amount = len(re.findall(sentence))
print(amount)
```

This SHOULD work. Though, I must admit I have never used re.findall, but what it looks like up there is that it creates a list of the numbers. So if the string is in a variable called sentence, and re.findall makes a list of numbers. Then Len should read the length of the list. Then it will print the length of the list.